# EZ Publish Articles

Tags: ezpublish

I have been using EZ Publish for a while but I am still a bit confused about the difference between the Article, Article (Subpage) and Article (Mainpage) content classes.

Just wondering what contexts these are meant to be used in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content classes in eZ Publish are a dime a dozen. eZ Publish ships with a bunch of 'default' content classes but you are not expected to use all of them. In sites I work on for instance I generally get rid fo the subpage and mainpage versions of the article and then modify the article class to better fit my needs. That is one of the strongest attributes of eZ Publish, the ability to create custom classes in the admin area and then just writing a custom template to serve up the content. Full documentation on what exactly an eZ Publish Class is can be found [here](http://bit.ly/NmSFBY). Remember to hit up the [eZ Publish Share site](http://bit.ly/J867cR), a place for eZ Publish developers to share questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I currently do something similar to you. I was just interested in what the thought behind these classes was, as I am trying to better understand how the stock CMS works to avoid unnecessary work

Answer (score 2):

The if you are using one of the built in designs (ezwebin for instance), the Article would typically be used for single page articles and the Article (Mainpage) and Article (Subpage) would be used to construct multi-page articles.

Use the Mainpage as the container and fill it will subpages (one for each page of your article) and the templates should add an Article Index with links to each page of the article.

If you want articles to be presented as just a single page use the plain Article class.